# java regex match a string

Tags: java, regex

Here is a string

```
* '''A happy man is too satisfied with the present to dwell too much on the future.'''
** &quot;My Future Plans&quot; an essay written at age 17 for school exam (18 September 1896) ''The Collected Papers of Albert Einstein'' Vol. 1 (1987) Doc.22
```

I need to get the text which starts with only one * till the end of that line

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*(.+?)\\n");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        s.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

I tried the above code, but it matches even 2 * and also the text from * to new line is not coming up properly, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?m)^\\*([^*].*)");
```

`(?m)` set the pattern in multiline mode where `^` means "begining of the line"

Adding `\\n` at the end is useless since the dot can't match a newline. (it's the reason why a lazy quantifier is useless too)

Comment: @Naren: The quantifiers *  and + are greedy by default and take all possible characters. Since `.` doesn't match a newline (or the end of the string) `.*` will stop automaticaly before the new line.

Comment: @Naren: take a look at the site: www.regular-expressions.info to have an explanation about lazy/greedy quantifiers

Answer (score 1):

which will make some sense i think,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\*[^*].+)");
```